# Failing to compile MonoGame on Boo compiler

Tags: monogame, boo

SharpDevelop compiles fine, but trying to compile through booc doesn't work.

```
Boo Compiler version 0.9.4.9 (CLR 2.0.50727.8000)
Program.boo(4,8): BCE0021: Namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework' not found, maybe
you forgot to add an assembly reference?
```

booc -resource:"C:\test\" Program.boo , the command used in Windows cmd tool.

Thank you. Alisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharpdevelop most likely already references the libraries to the compiler for you. What that means is, when you manually invoke the booc command line compiler, you will have to tell the compiler where exactly the MonoGame library is. I haven't been able to check myself yet, but I did have a quick look at the command lines and the Boo source code, and I think you have to do the following:

`-lib:C:/Path/To/MonoGame/Libraries`

This will tell the compiler where to look for additional libraries.
The next thing you should then do is add the libraries you want, eg:

`-r:Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll,Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll`

Add these two additional compiler options to your command line and I think it should work.
I haven't compiled this myself really, because I found it rather tedious. Instead, I decided to create my own build script in Boo itself in order to compile my Boo programs. That way I still had to add the library path and reference the libraries, as in the following snippet:

```
def CompileEngine() as bool:
"""Compiles the engine and puts it in ./lib/SpectralEngine.dll"""

    compiler                       = BooCompiler()
    compiler.Parameters.Pipeline   = CompileToFile()
    compiler.Parameters.OutputType = CompilerOutputType.Library
    compiler.Parameters.Ducky      = true
    compiler.Parameters.LibPaths.Add("./lib")
    compiler.Parameters.OutputAssembly = "./lib/SpectralEngine.dll"

    # Add libraries.
    compiler.Parameters.References.Add(compiler.Parameters.LoadAssembly("OpenTK.dll"))
    compiler.Parameters.References.Add(compiler.Parameters.LoadAssembly("NAudio.dll"))
    compiler.Parameters.References.Add(compiler.Parameters.LoadAssembly("Boo.Lang.dll"))
    compiler.Parameters.References.Add(compiler.Parameters.LoadAssembly("Boo.Lang.Parser.dll"))
    compiler.Parameters.References.Add(compiler.Parameters.LoadAssembly("Boo.Lang.Compiler.dll"))

    # Take all boo files from the Engine source directory.
    files = (Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + """/src/Engine""", "*.boo", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where({file as string | return not file.Contains("Gwen")})) # Filter out old GWEN files.

    for file in files:
        print "Adding file: " + file
        compiler.Parameters.Input.Add(FileInput(file))

    print "Compiling to ./lib/SpectralEngine.dll"
    context = compiler.Run()

    if context.GeneratedAssembly is null:
        print "Failed to compile:\n" + join(e for e in context.Errors, "\n")
        return false
    else:
        return true
```

I've put two of these build scripts at [here](https://github.com/Shammah/Spectral-Universe/blob/master/build.boo) and [here](https://github.com/Shammah/Prospector/blob/dev/build.boo). It's perhaps a bit overkill for you, though.

Comment: I used the following command: booc -lib:"C:\Workplace\Switch\bin\Debug" Program.boo, since Debug folder contains all the dlls needed, but using -r breaks it. I get the following error: BCE0021: Namespace 'Switch.Helpers' not found. How do you include your own boo files?

Comment: I have no idea what switch is. If it's a library compiled before-hand,  you should get it to work the same way you did with MonoGame. If it's one or more source (.boo) files, you should of course include those source files as well. You can add folders with source files with the -srcdir options. `-srcdir:DIR | Adds DIR as a directory where sources can be found`

Comment: Switch is just the name of the game I'm working on. booc -lib:"D:\Workplace\Switch\Switch\bin\Debug" -srcdir:"D:\Workplace\Switch\Switch" -r:Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll,Microsoft.Xna.Fr
amework.Game.dll Program.boo
Boo Compiler version 0.9.4.9 (CLR 2.0.50727.8000)
Fatal error: Cannot find assembly: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'. Still cannot get it to compile >_<. Sorry, I'm new to Boo, only got on it like a couple of days ago.